# Linux group permissions?

Tags: linux

I was wondering if anyone could explain a bit on Linux permissions for me. I have two groups

```
Group A - Normal Users
Group B - File Changing group
```

I want group B to be pretty much exactly the same as group A other than group B are able to change 'message of the day' how could I set it so they have write access to MOTD and group A only have read access?

Comment: chmod is the function. http://www.onlineconversion.com/html_chmod_calculator.htm . chmod 750 will give owner all permissions, others within your group wil have read and execute only and noone outside can do anything. Chown to change ownership

Comment: This question is better suited for a site like SuperUser.

Comment: Either way I just got my answer! Thanks @nneonneo

Comment: You might find [this blog post](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/04/22/linux-permissions-demystified/) helpful in understand Linux permissions.

Answer (score 2):

With ordinary UNIX u-g-o permissions, you can only assign a single UNIX group to any given file. In your case, since "normal users" presumably means "all users", you could just `chmod` the MOTD file to `664` (group read-write, all read-only), and `chown` it to `root:file_changers` (file owned by root, and assigned to the file_changers group).

---

With Linux ACLs, you can assign multiple groups to a file. Not all filesystems support ACLs. You can use `setfacl` to alter the permissions:

```
setfacl -m g:regular:r motd
setfacl -m g:file_changers:rw motd
```

Note that, in my opinion, ACLs can often be overkill. They can make permission management a hassle if you aren't prepared for them. Consider carefully if you need them; otherwise, stick to the simpler UNIX permission system.

Answer (score 0):

Solution without ACL:s:

You can move the motd file in a directory that is readable by group A and make the file writable by group B. Then place a symlink in place from the original location to the new location.

Example (assuming motd is in /etc/motd):

```
# mkdir /etc/motd-dir
# mv /etc/motd /etc/motd-dir/
# chown groupA /etc/motd-dir
# chown groupB /etc/motd-dir/motd
# chmod 750 /etc/motd-dir
# chmod 664 /etc/motd-dir/motd
# ln -s /etc/motd-dir/motd /etc/motd
```

This solution requires that all members of group B must also belong to group A so they can access the directory.