# How to set permission to a directory with multiple groups with ansible?

Tags: ansible

I want to set two groups to a directory

- app_group
- td-agent

If use `file` module, there is a `group` attribute can do

```
- name: Set group to directory
  file:
    path: /app
    group: app_group
    state: directory
    recurse: true
    mode: '0774'
```

The current permissions like

```
$ ls -la /app/app1/
drwxrwx---. 5 root      app_group   31 Oct 11 14:12 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root      root        21 May 12 2021  ..
drwxrwx---. 3 app_user  app_group   12 Apr 28 13:30 product
```

But I want to set Fluentd's user group `td-group` can also read files in /app directory. Like /app/app1/product/001.log. How to do?

---

If change `mode` to `mode: o+rx`, other user can read/execute the directory. Will it change current permission for `app_user` and `app_group`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the underlying operating system seems to be Linux, the answer to your question

> How to set permission to a directory with multiple groups?

will be you can't do that. At least not in that way. Ansible can configure only what is available.

So you may have a look into the basic concepts of [how to manage Linux permissions for users, groups, and others](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/manage-permissions).

**In example**

- [Linux group permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452599/)
- [Granting write permissions to a group to a folder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116070/)
- [How does group permissions work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408785/)

and maybe put the `fluentd` user into `app_group`. An other approach could be introducing Access Control Lists (ACL).

**In example**

- [How can I give permissions of files to multiple groups?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447762/)
- [Two Groups Separate Permissions, One Directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596939/)